Why is the compiler checking this concept and generating an error?
Compiling the following code results in: error: satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires(T v) {bar(v);} [with T = T]' depends on itself.
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


template<class T>
concept Barable = requires(T v)
{
    bar(v);
};

struct Foo
{
    template<class T> requires Barable<T>
    Foo(T) {};
};

void bar(Foo) {
    std::cout << "Foo";
};

void bar(std::vector<Foo>) {
    std::cout <<  "vector";
}

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<Foo>{};
    bar(v);
}

I understand how checking this concept leads to a circular dependency. What I don't understand is why, with this setup, the compiler gives an error.
From my understanding, it should just not add bar(Foo) to the overload set and use bar(std::vector<Foo>). For any other type it seems to work that way.
Notes:

I checked with the trunk versions of both gcc and clang
marking Foo(T) explicit, or providing a constructor Foo(std::vector<Foo>) solves the problem
changing to some other type (e.g. int or std::vector<int>) solves the problem
Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6qxTrzMd8
I originally stumbled upon this when playing around with Sean Parent's 'Inheritance is the base class of all evil' code


Note msvc compiles this code while gcc and clang rejects it.

It seems the compiler is trying to perform an overload resolution between bar(std::vector<Foo>) and bar(Foo). The latter could theoretically be called via bar(Foo{v}), using Foo's converting constructor. For that, the compiler needs to determine whether Foo{v} is viable, and that depends on whether vector<Foo> is Barable, and that in turn requires checking bar(v) for v of type std::vector<Foo>, coming full circle.

@IgorTandetnik I agree. The strange thing is that there is no such error for other types, such as std::vector, or for the 'equivalent' constraint using SFINAE.

I know why vector<int> works but vector<Foo> doesn't. When defining Barable concept, bar is an undeclared identifier. Being a dependent name, it's looked up again at the point of instantiation - but only via argument-dependent lookup, not via ordinary lookup. When you call bar(std::vector<Foo>{}), the global namespace is associated with the type of the argument, and bar(Foo) is found. When you call bar(std::vector<int>{}), the global namespace is not thus associated, and no overload of bar is found. Therefore, vector<int> is unambiguously not Barable.

If you introduce struct Baz{}; and try again with std::vector<Baz>, the error comes back. It's not that vector<Foo> is special - any class in the global namespace would allow Barable instantiation to find bar(Foo) via the argument-dependent lookup, and start the cycle.

bar(MyType{}); doesn't work for me either. Perhaps I misunderstood the changes you expected to be made.

@IgorTandetnik Re bar(MyType{}): you made the correct changes, I'm a bit confused why I remembered this one to work - I must've had a slightly different setup than I thought when testing it. That certain types don't trigger the error because of not triggering ADL makes sense to me. I'd be happy to accept an answer based on that.

Does this answer your question? Resolving function overload in requires clause

With two-phase name lookup, the name bar within the definition of Barable is looked up at two points - at the point of definition using ordinary lookup, and again at the point of instantiation, using argument-dependent lookup (ADL) only. Since the name bar is not declared before the definition of Barable, the first phase doesn't find anything. So the concept relies entirely on finding bar by ADL at the point of instantiation.
When you later do
SomeType arg;
bar(arg);

the compiler finds bar(Foo) declaration via ordinary lookup, and needs to determine whether it's viable: it could be a call to bar(Foo{arg}) using Foo's converting constructor. So it needs to instantiate that converting constructor, which requires instantiating Barable<SomeType> concept.
This could go one of two ways. If SomeType is not associated with global namespace (as would be the case with e.g. std::vector<int>, or plain int, or SomeNamespace::SomeType), then ADL doesn't find any declaration of bar; such a type is unambiguously not Barable.
If SomeType is in fact associated with the global namespace (as would be the case with e.g. vector<Foo>, or Baz, or std::vector<Baz> for some type Baz declared in the global namespace), then bar(Foo) is found. Then as part of instantiating Barable<SomeType>, the compiler needs to instantiate bar(Foo{v}) for v of type SomeType - but recall that we are already in the middle of instantiating exactly that. Hence the error that the concept depends on itself.

Considering user12002570's comment, which compiler is correct, then, according to the standard?

@LHLaurini I would put my money on GCC and Clang. But I must admit I can't cite chapter and verse off the top, and am too lazy to research it.
